# How can I add fade from top to visual effect view Blur - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview

how can I add fade from top to visual effect view Blur? 
I want the top edge not visible.

Example:

[image]

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffect.Style.dark)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Comment: I don't think you're going to do that with a simple blur effect view. More likely you would need to pass the image through a CIFilter.

Comment: @matt it can not be done using Shape Layer?

Comment: If we ignore the "blur" part, you can easily do this with a gradient mask. But what happens when you apply the blur is not so clear, because it composites in a weird way. That is why I suggest you blur using a filter and now you can gradient mask the result (as part of the filter or as a separate mask).

Comment: @matt I want to add a video and then I can not use CIFilter

Comment: There is no video in your question. I suggest you start over and say more clearly what you are really trying to do and why it isn't working.

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
extension UIView{
    func createGradientBlur() {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [
        UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor,
        UIColor.white.withAlphaComponent(1).cgColor]
        let viewEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .light)
        let effectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: viewEffect)
        effectView.frame = CGRect(x: self.bounds.origin.x, y: self.bounds.size.height, width: self.bounds.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)
        gradientLayer.frame = effectView.bounds
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0 , y: 0.3)
        effectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight]
        effectView.layer.mask = gradientLayer
        effectView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false //Use this to pass touches under this blur effect
        addSubview(effectView)

    }
}
```

How to use:

```
var myView = UIView()
myView.createGradientBlur()
```

Comment: Definitely do not do this. It won't resize properly and may crash or leak.  While the idea of using a mask is correct, you simply do it as in the example answer.

Answer (score 1):

how it's done:

```
class UpwardsBlurEdge: UIVisualEffectView {
    
    lazy var grad: CAGradientLayer = {
        let g = CAGradientLayer()
        g.colors = [
            UIColor.white.cgColor,
            UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ]
        g.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        g.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0)
        layer.mask = g
        return g
    }()
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        grad.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

You can simply drop a UIVisualEffectView in on storyboard, and then change the class to that. Or just add it from code.